# How to handle instance's external, mutual and attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
class ppl:
    gender = "male"      
    def __init__(self, name, age, username):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.username = username

username = "abcs"
laci = ppl("John", 25, username)

for attr, value in laci.__dict__.iteritems():
   print value
```

How do i make the program to print the gender as well?

Comment: Iterate over `dict(ppl.__dict__, **laci.__dict__).iteritems()` and filter out attributes that start and end with  `__`.

Comment: Also i only need the values not the keys to be printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than make `gender` a class attribute, just make it a hard-coded instance attribute:

```
 def __init__(self, name, age, username):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.username = username
    self.gender = "male"
```

This make more sense than a hard-coded class attribute. Either all instances of `ppl` are males, in which case there is no need to explicitly store the information (in fact, the class should probably be called `Male`, not `ppl`), or the instances could be male or female, in which case gender isn't an attribute of the class as a whole.

Comment: Amazing answer! And so simple, this is exactly the idea i was in need of! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a class attribute so use the class:

```
print(ppl.gender)
```

Or print it using the instance:

```
print(laci.gender)
```

To combine both class and instances dicts:

```
for attr, value in laci.__dict__.viewitems() | ppl.__dict__.iteritems():
   if not all((attr.startswith("__"),attr.endswith("__"))):
       print(value)
```

Comment: Id like it to work its way through all of the attributes, without me printing them all out one by one

Comment: Then combine the class dict items